# How to click on "dynamic" link using Selenium Webdriver with chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm trying to write a program that will open livestreams of Basketball games from links provided by reddit's nbastreams page. I can open the reddit nbastreams, click the link with the user inputted teams to be watched, but am having trouble clicking the actual links that lead to the streams. Each page for a different game will have different streams, but the basic setup of the page is the same. Here is the code I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

team = input("Team?: ")
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/nbastreams/') #opens first webpage

elm = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(team) #opens the page with streams for the specific game inputted
elm.click()
```

The goal is to read the table with the links to the streams listed, and then automatically open a few in different tabs.

Comment: There are a lot of links to different streams on that page. Which of them do you want to visit or extract?

Comment: Can .u explain where u want to click